# How do I write a function that accepts both string and int64 types in Go?

Tags: go, types

I have function that looks like this

```
func GetMessage(id string, by string) error {
    // mysql query goes here
}
```

I have `message_id` which is string and `id` which is primary key.

I would like to accept both types for id parameter.

I have tried like this

```
if (by == "id") {
        int_id, err := strconv.ParseInt(id, 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        id = int_id
    }
```

But I'm getting error like

```
cannot use int_id (type int64) as type string in assignment
```

can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: The reason of the error, is because your function is accepting just string, so why you're converting the id? You could just pass it to your function as it is.

Comment: I need to pass that as int for mysql where clause. Thats why i'm converting the id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `interface{}` like this working sample:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "errors"

func GetMessage(id interface{}) error {
    //fmt.Printf("v:%v\tT: %[1]T \n", id)
    switch v := id.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println("Hello " + v)
    case int64:
        fmt.Println(v + 101)
    default:
        //panic("Unknown type: id.")
        return errors.New("Unknown type: id.")
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    message_id := "World"
    id := int64(101)
    GetMessage(message_id)
    GetMessage(id)
}
```

output:

```
Hello World
202
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That helps a lot